# Как сделать выборку из таблицы используя JOIN?

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

Как сделать выборку данных из таблицы вместе с родительским на которую  есть ссылка на внешнем ключе дочернего, учитывая что его там может и не быть.

Вывожу заказ а там есть внешний ключ на курьера.А мне нужно вывести заказы у которых есть курьер и тех у кого нету курьера.

```
    public List<MyOrder> test(){
            Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyOrder.class);

            criteria.createCriteria("courier");
            //если добавляю это то получаю только 
            //те записи у которых на внешнем ключе есть запись.Мне нужно вывести 
            //строку из таблицы `courier` если он не null,иначе без него.

            List<MyOrder> orders = criteria.list();
            return orders;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь нужно что-типа:

```
criteria.createAlias("courier", "courier", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое.